# Laravel 5.2 unit test set headers not working

Tags: php, laravel, api, unit-testing, laravel-5

I have the following assert:

```
$this->call('GET', '/api/v1/ubication/suggest', [
            'term' => 'a'
        ], [], [], ['Accept' => 'application/json']);

$this->assertResponseStatus(422);
```

The **call** method definition is as follow:

```
public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null) {

}
```

I'm passing my header in the $server position but i still get 302 status code in the response(I'm testing a Request validation) instead of 422 that is what i expect.

How can i simulate that header in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a GET call with Headers, you can use:

```
$this->get($url, $headers);
```

Example:

```
$this->get('/oauth', [ 'HTTP_X_API_KEY' => 'xxxx' ]);
```

Since you are making a GET request, your parameters can be included in the `$url`.

[Source](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_get)

Comment: Perfect! I would add that the query string can be hardcoded in $url or be included in the $headers array, as i have checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use

```
$this->call('GET', '/api/v1/ubication/suggest', [
            'term' => 'a'
        ], [], [], ['Accept' => 'application/json']);
```

The reason it did not work is that behind the scenes Laravel filters out any header that does not start with "HTTP_"

So all you need to do is replace 'Accept' with 'HTTP_Accept'

````
$this->call('GET', '/api/v1/ubication/suggest', [
            'term' => 'a'
        ], [], [], ['HTTP_Accept' => 'application/json']);
```
````